# how to use cssSelecotr in selenium Java

Tags: selenium, automation

Want to find the text "Admin review" from below xml. How can i use the cssSelector (or other method) to find it?  Below one doesn't work:

```
WebElement e = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("vt-proposal-status-indicator .ng-binding"));
```

Can anybody help to take a look?

Comment: <h5 id="proposalStatus" ng-if="proposal.status.key != 'PREPARING'" class="ng-scope">
              <span class="status-label label label-danger" ng-class="{'label-danger':        proposal.statusReason.key == 'DEADLINE_POLICY',
                           'label-info': proposal.status.key == 'SUBMITTED',

Comment: 'label-warning': proposal.status.key == 'ROUTING' || proposal.status.key == 'PENDING_DECISION',
                           'label-success': proposal.status.key == 'APPROVED' || proposal.status.key == 'REVIEWED' || proposal.status.key == 'AWARDED',

Comment: 'label-default': proposal.status.key == 'CLOSED' || proposal.status.key == 'DECLINED' || proposal.status.key == 'WITHDRAWN'}">
                <vt-proposal-status-indicator status="proposal.status.key" reason="proposal.statusReason.key" class="ng-isolate-scope"><span class="deadline-policy">
<span class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle" ng-if="mapping.icons.length==1"></span>
</span>

Comment: </vt-proposal-status-indicator>
<!-- ngIf: proposal.status.key == 'ON_HOLD' || proposal.status.key == 'CLOSED' -->
<span ng-if="proposal.status.key == 'ON_HOLD' || proposal.status.key == 'CLOSED'" class="ng-binding ng-scope">Admin review</span>
<!-- end ngIf: proposal.status.key == 'ON_HOLD' || proposal.status.key == 'CLOSED' -->
 <!-- ngIf: proposal.status.key != 'ON_HOLD' && proposal.status.key != 'CLOSED' -->
 </span>
  </h5>

Comment: Instead of comments update the question with the relevant _HTML_ for effective answers.

Comment: ^^ As above comment. Please edit [mcve] HTML into the question and delete the comments.

Answer (score 0):

```
String text = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("span.ng-binding")).getText()
```

This will get the text of the desired element. https://try.jsoup.org/ is a good location to build and test your CSS selectors.

Also, as the commenters above mentioned, please review and follow the [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) guidelines in your questions.